# Admin-on-Rest Custom button and populate page

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there a way to make a custom button that will take you to a page, and then have it so you can show data in a DataGrid?

For example, say we have a DataGrid and you click on the show button for a post with the `id = John`. The show button would take you to `/resource/id/show` and in there you can have a DataGrid with all the attributes of John.

So I want to make a button to take me to `/resource/id/name`  instead of show where I can have a Datagrid with properties of `name` from the specific `id`.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can :) You should:

- declare a [custom route](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customroutes) for your custom page
- create a button component that you pass to the List component [actions](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#actions)

Comment: Do you have an example of a custom route that is not that tutorial? I am looking for something that is actually being used; the tutorial seems very basic and doesn't get into complex routes. @Gildas

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto same question to you as Gilas.

Comment: No, you'll have to do it yourself. It's just React and React Router, so there is nothing specific to admin-on-rest in that case.